# Crystal report not opening in client machine for VS 2015 run time 13.0

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I know this question has been asked many times, I tried almost all the possible way to make this happen. But still it is throwing exception like as follows.

```
The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception.
```

The Crystal report run time has been installed in client machine, screen shot attached of the assembly folder screenshots and the reference added with application.
The application is created using VS2015. [image]

Am I missing any reference to be added , or need to install something else in the client machine?

Comment: Check the windows event log for more details. Does it run on the dev machine? As you have both versions installed there, maybe the application is trying to load version 10 on the client.

Comment: Deleted and recreated the setup file , now working fine.